# How to disable ADF triggers in DEV but keep them enabled in PROD with Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I've set up a Azure CI/CD pipeline which automatically builds the ARM template to be used for the adf_publish branch after updating the main branch. When ready, I can execute the release pipeline to integrate all changes to my PROD ADF. When releasing, all triggers will be paused and after deployment they will be enabled again.

However, I noticed that the triggers I run in DEV are also being enabled in PROD. After deployment to PROD I don't want that trigger to run in DEV anymore as this will trigger the ADF pipelines twice at the same time.

Making use of parameterized values is on my to-do list, but I don't need all the data that is being process in PROD, in my DEV environment as well.

Is there any way of disabling the DEV triggers after releasing to PROD?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a task after deploying all the changes to PROD that stops all your triggers in DEV.

Example:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'Data Factory: Stop all triggers'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azConnection }}'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: | 
      $triggers = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName ${{ parameters.resourcegroupName }} -DataFactoryName ${{ parameters.dataFactoryName }} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    
      if($triggers) {
        foreach($trigger in $triggers) {
          Stop-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName ${{ parameters.resourcegroupName }} -DataFactoryName ${{ parameters.dataFactoryName }} -Name $trigger.TriggerName -Force
        }
      }
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this out when I have the time.

Comment: That would edit the code on DEV and next deploy would stop all triggers in PROD, no?

Comment: You can add a condition on your task which will be executed per environment (Only in Dev for example)